# JQuery Json Issue always get

Tags: javascript, jquery

It always returns 200 OK, but jQuery executes the error event. I tried a lot of things, but I could not figure out the problem. I am adding my code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#manual').click(function(){
    var id = $('#manual_text').val();
    $.ajax({
      url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin/get_data_id",
      type: "POST",
      data: { 'tag': id },
      success: function(data)
      {
        alert(data);
      },
      error: function()
      {
        alert("Error");
      }
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: add the error as a fail and console.log(error). Just alerting "Error" only tells you there is one, not what it is

Comment: I would also check your dev tools to see what the actual response is

Comment: If you're getting 200 code and it's reporting an error, it's usually because the JSON is not valid. Check the Response in the Network tab of DevTools.

Comment: a string as a response

Comment: A common mistake is having some HTML before or after the JSON.

Comment: okay so issue can be of dataType?

Comment: @FarrukhK.Jadoon You have no `dataType` option, so it will try to figure it out. If the server sends `Content-type: application/json` then it will try to parse it as JSON.

Comment: i am echoing the data on page and get response back

Comment: Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
AlexaToolbar-ALX_NS_PH: AlexaToolbar/alx-4.0.3
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 9
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Host: [::1]
Origin: http://[::1]
Referer: http://[::1]/warehouse/index.php/admin/get_tags
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest

Comment: content type is Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;

Comment: @Barmar Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; this is my content type

Comment: That's from the request header, we care about the response header.

Comment: what i have to do i need really help

Comment: Never `alert( data )`. Rather `console.log( data )`. Don't use `alert` for debugging purposes!

Comment: I think this should be the executed php file folder, please check : url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin/get_data_id",